# Reference return variable in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to come up with a program that will take a double value, such as 47.63 and break it down into its respective bills/coins (4 10s, 1 five, 2 ones, etc).

I made a function called `counter` that takes an input for a double amount (e.x. 47.63), a currency, and then the name of that currency) and returns a double called `remainder`. Currently I am thinking that I would like to use the return value `remainder` and put it into the same function again such that I can call something like this in my main function.

```
counter(total_money, tens, "ten dollar bills");
counter(remainder, fives, "five dollar bills");
```

How can I then reference the return value `remainder` for future use?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoneyCalculator {

    public static double counter(double total_money, double currency, String currency_name) {
        int i;
        // for loop to subtract 10's out
        for (i = 0; total_money - currency > 0; i++) {
            total_money = total_money - currency;
        }

        double remainder = total_money;
        System.out.printf("%d " + currency_name + "\n", i);
        System.out.printf("%f remaining\n", remainder);
        return remainder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a double\n");
        double total_money = scan.nextDouble();  //47.63

        double tens = 10.00,
                fives = 5.00,
                ones = 1.00,
                quarters = 0.25,
                dimes = 0.10,
                nickles = 0.05,
                pennies = 0.01;

        int tenbills, fivebills, onebills, quartercoins, dimecoins, nicklecoins, pennycoins;

        counter(total_money, tens, "ten dollar bills");
        // counter(remainder, fives, "five dollar bills");
    }
}
```

Taking an answer from below, the following solution works, but it seems messy. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
double remainder = counter(total_money, tens, "ten dollar bill(s)");
double remainder_1 = counter(remainder, fives, "five dollar bill(s)");
double remainder_2 = counter(remainder_1, ones, "one dollar bill(s)");
double remainder_3 = counter(remainder_2, quarters, "quarter(s)");
double remainder_4 = counter(remainder_3, dimes, "dime(s)");
double remainder_5 = counter(remainder_4, nickles, "nickle(s)");
counter(remainder_5, pennies, "penny(s)");
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `remainder` as input as well as output?

Comment: yes, just not for the first `counter` call

Comment: you have used primitive `double`, and all the primitive in java are `pass-by-value`. So only the value will be passed into the method, not the reference.

Comment: Even if you will use wrapper `Double` class, that is also imutable. As if you will change the value it will create a ne Object.

Comment: The best way to achieve the same is to create a POJO class with these fields and use that.

Comment: Why can't you reuse the same variable?

Comment: The pattern you are trying to implement needs recursion if you want something elegant.

Answer (score 2):

instead of calling it like: `counter(total_money, tens, "ten dollar bills");`
Store the return value in a variable like so: `double remainder = counter(total_money, tens, "ten dollar bills");`

Comment: Thanks. The code works, but it looks pretty messy having to store 7 different `remainder_1, remainder_2`, etc.

Comment: there are many ways you can modify your code, one of which could be making it a recursive function that calls itself until you have found all the remainders.

Answer (score 0):

First start by defining your denominations in a list. You could use an Enum for these.

```
public enum Denomination {

  TENS(10.0, "ten dollar bill(s)"), 
  FIVES(5.0, "five dollar bill(s)"), 
  //... etc.

  private final double amount;
  private final String description;

  Denomination(double amount, String description) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
  }

  double getAmount() {
    return this.amount;
  }

  double getDescription() {
    return this.description;
  }
}
```

Then create a list of them, in the right order, simply by:

```
private static final List<Denominations> denominations = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(TENS, FIVES, ONES, QUARTERS, DIMES , NICKELS, PENNIES));
```

We make it unmodifiable, so that you don't mess it by mistake. Put it somewhere at the top.

Then change your `counter()` function to be recursive:

```
public static void counter(double money, Queue<Denominations> remainingDenominations) {
  if (remainingDenominations.isEmpty()) {
    return;
  }

  //get the next denomination, and remove it from the list
  Denomination denomination = remainingDenominations.remove();

  //calculate how many times the denomination amount fits in the money (rounded down to the nearest whole `int`)
  int times = money / denomination.getAmount();

  //calculate the remainder 
  double remainder = money - (denomination.getAmount() * times);

  System.out.printf("%d %s", times, denomination.getDescription());
  System.out.printf("%f remaining\n", remainder);

  counter(remainder, remainingDenominations);
}
```

Then to use it, just copy the list of denominations into a `LinkedList` (so that the original one remains intact), and call `counter()` once.

```
counter(total_money, new LinkedList<>(denominations));
```

You can even make it return the denomination amounts in a `Map` rather than just outputing it and losing it:

```
 private static Map<Denomination, Integer> counter(double money, Queue<Denomination> remainingDenominations, Map<Denomination, Integer> accumulated) {

  if (remainingDenominations.isEmpty()) {
    return accumulated;
  }

  //... same logic as before ...

  accumulated.put(denomination, times);
  counter(remainder, remainingDenominations, denomination);
}

/**
  * A simpler overloaded version for the initial entry point.
  */
public static Map<Denomination, Integer> counter(double money) {
  return counter(money,  new LinkedList<>(denominations), new LinkedHashMap<>());
}
```

This way using it becomes even simpler:

```
Map<Denomination, Integer> counts = counter(total_money);

counts.forEach((denomination, amount) -> System.out.println("%d %s", amount, denomination.getDescription());
```

And you can do whatever you want with the counts.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(Denomination.values()).sorted(comparingDouble(Denomination::getValue).reversed()).collect(toList())` is (arguably) more expressive of the actual intent, and less error-prone than building the list manually.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, that's true. Nice observation and improvement.

Answer (score -1):

Return value assign into a new double variable then you can return that variable.